# Azure Remote Debugging object reference when attaching debugger

Tags: c#, azure, debugging

I am trying to remote debug with Microsoft Azure. My IDE is Visual Studio 2015. When I try to attach the debugger, I get an error below:
[image]

I tried to clean project and re-attach, but same error. What seems to cause the issue?

Comment: Looks like you have some problems with Cloud Explorer in Visual Studio. Have you installed the latest updates for VS?

Comment: yes latest updates are installed

Comment: I have the same issue!

Answer (score 1):

I found solution and it helps me!

First, go to Debug -> attach to process.

Then, in Qualifier field type your website like my-website.com.

Click Find and enter credentials from publish profile.

Select MyProjectName.exe from processes.

[Here is the link to article.](https://blog.jsinh.in/remote-debugging-azure-mobile-service-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object/#.WQIErIh96Ul)

Comment: VS 2017 informs that "no symbols were loaded". I use debug configuration.